# Flutter Widget rebuild after one of the property changed

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-state

How to manage to force a Widget to rebuild immediately after one of the property value has changed?
Some pseudo code:

```
class Live extends StatefulWidget {

  String name;
Live(this.name);

  @override
  _LiveState createState() => _LiveState();
}

class _LiveState extends State<Live> {

 // some turbo logic I don't want to move to Live class
 ..

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(childrens: [
    Text(widget.name),
    Card(content calculated based on turbo logic),
    ]
      
    );
  }
}
```

When `String name`  property has updated (based on parent's setState call), everything is happening in real time. The change is reflected immediately in Text widget. The value is visible immediately only because i am using `widget.name` call so in `built()` method I am using property from `Live` class instead of State.

The problem is that another widget wrapped in Card is calculated in place marked as `// some turbo logic I don't want to move to Live class`. Due to this fact when I want to see updates in this section I need to switch tab and go to e.g Setting and then return to Live tab to see changes related to Card content. I believe it trigger build() method again.

Golas:

- Once the `name` value is updated in Live widget, a State widget rebuilds immediately.
- do not move `turbo logic` to Live class and keep it in State class

Answer (score 0):

First off, your `StatefulWidget` should be immutable and therefore only contain immutable fields. I'd suggest you move the `name` field into `State` and change it there using a setter. The setter should call `setState()`, this will cause the desired rebuild.

See [this introduction](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulWidget-class.html) for more information - specifically the "Bird" sample code to see how to code a setter.

Comment: I use setState() method in Parent Widget and I believe this method will update child descendants. It's not happening. 
The example on the flutter side is not showing how to update internal State object from the Outside.